# How to access a constant from within a class method

Tags: php, oop, constants

I'm migrating a php application from procedural to oop.
I use a DEBUG constant to activate errors and warnings output (in fact, I have thee, every one makes the output more verbose.
But I can't find a way to access those constants from within a method.
The constants are defined before autoload in a separate file.

In the utility file I have

```
define('DEBUG', TRUE);
```

And inside a given method I tried to

```
if(!defined('DEBUG')) define('DEBUG', FALSE);
```

But I always end up with DEBUG=FALSE.
What am I doing wrong? I'm a total noob to oop, so be gentle please :-)

Clarification

Every class has his own file.
In any given script, the first thing I do is to include the utility file. The utility file is the one who defines DEBUG and has the _autoload function.

```
script_file.php
 includes utility_file.php
  defines DEBUG
  has _autoload function
```

Comment: Normally defines are available anywhere. Seemed, you have a problem with file loading.

Comment: so the utility defines the constant DEBUG, then what's up with the _autoload function? Where is the function that checks if DEBUG is defined? Is it the autoloaded function? or somewhere after the include?

Comment: autoload load the needed classes. the methods inside those classes are the ones who try to use DEBUG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

darkphoenix was right, This wasn't an OOP problem. This was a NetBeans problem.
I'm using NetBeand and uploading the files to a remote server upon save. I've set the DEBUG constant to TRUE in the utility file and hit save on NetBeans, the save process (apparently) went without problems (no warnings or anything).
Big was my surprise when latter I logged in via SSH did a cat on the file. The file was never saved to the server. My local copy has my last edit, but the remote one doesn't...
Moral of the story: I hate you NetBeans

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php), you should access DEBUG (no prepending $) in your code directly. are you including or requiring your utility file in the same file that has the function you're talking about? i don't think this is an OOP problem

Comment: That's why I can't understand what's happening here... I added a clarification in the question

Comment: I can acces the DEBUG constant from all the procedural functions. But Inside a class, it's like it never existed...